# Save large vector of numbers to hard disk drive

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I allocated a large chunk of continuous bytes in the RAM using a vector of type unsigned short.

```
vector<unsigned short> testDump(204800000);

for(int k = 0; k<204800000; k++)
    testDump[k] = 9; \\ This is different in my real program
```

Now I want to save this vector into my hard disk drive. How and what's the fastest way to do that? The size of the data is fairly large (~1/2 GB). I tried the following:

```
ofstream outfile("allMyNumbers.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
outfile.write(&testDump[0], testDump.size());
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned short *' to 'const char *'
```

What's the fastest way to accomplish my task, which is to save the vector to a file using the fastest approach?

*The platform is Windows 7.

Comment: This surely must depend on the platform you're targeting.

Comment: Memory mapped files may fit here, depending on the platform.

Comment: My platform is Windows 7. Edited

Comment: The size of your data isn't ~1/2 GB, it's closer to 3.81 GB.

Comment: Oh sorry. I had an extra 0. Edited. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

One platform-independent technique would be to use an `ostream_iterator` for the type your vector-class holds.  Since the type your vector contains is already overloaded for `operator<<` for an `ostream` class-type, you shouldn't have any issues instantiating the template for the `ostream_iterator` class for your vector-type. You would then combined the `ostream_iterator` with the `copy` algorithm from the STL to iterate through your vector, and serialize the raw bytes to the file.  Using `operator<<` will use up a lot more data than using `ofstream::write`, which writes the raw binary data to disk, but has the advantage of serializing the data, making it independently readable on any platform.

So for instance:

```
vector<unsigned short> testDump(2048000000);
//...fill in your vector

ofstream outfile("allMyNumbers.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);

//tab-delinate the data
ostream_iterator<unsigned short> o_iter(outfile, "\t");
copy(testDump.begin(), testDump.end(), o_iter);
```

Comment: Maybe a separator between the values is in order. Granted, the questioner didn't specify that it be possible to read the data back in future, but I think that can be assumed.

Comment: Definitely a good idea ... although for a binary file, it would have to be some type of "magic" number rather than simply a char-delimiter, unless that character was not going to be part of the actual output itself to begin with.  Typically a binary file would have a header with pointers to the raw data portion and specifications on the size of each readable section of data in order to avoid delimiter ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How would I do that if I may ask (it doesn't need to stay in binary, I can use dec). By the way, it's taking forever to finish. It still hasn't finished (3 mins so far)

Comment: @Jason: in your code, the numbers are all written to the stream as base-10 ASCII. The fact that the file is opened in binary mode is nothing to do with it. So any character other than the digits 0-9 would serve as a separator. If the values were saved in binary format, then it could be arranged that no separator is required, the values can be written as fixed width.

Comment: @SteveJessop : I thought we set the `ios::binary` flag ... why would that still write variable-length ASCII base-10 digits to disk?  Doesn't setting that flag write the raw bytes to disk (in this case, depending on the platform size for `unsigned short`, that would be two bytes per number) in whatever the platform-specific endian ordering was?

Comment: @Jason: actually it's ~400MB. I had an extra 0 by mistake. It took 281 seconds to save it. Is that natural? And how would I add a separator? Thanks

Comment: @Jason: no, it doesn't. All the `binary` flag does is control whether linebreaks and (rarely) end-of-file characters are treated specially. It has no effect on the formatted I/O operators.

Comment: @RoronoaZoro : Per Steve's comments, since you're actually writing out decimal numbers in ASCII rather than the raw two-byte binary data stored in your vector, you're writing a lot more than 400MB if most of you numbers are larger than two decimal digits in length.  Secondly, you can add any ASCII delimiter by simply adding a second argument to the constructor of the `ostream_iterator` ... and just make the delimiter any non-numerical character.  The downside of this approach is that you get data-bloat ... the upside is the serialization process is platform independent.

Comment: @SteveJessop : Okay, I see the confusion ... `write()` dumps the raw binary data, `operator<<` serializes an `unsigned short` into its ASCII representation.

Comment: -1 Because he specifically asked for the fastest way and formatted output to a stream is anything but fast. A quick test in VC10 with full optimizations gives me write speeds of about 1.1MB/s.

Comment: @Jason: when trying to add the delimiter (as you show in your example above), the file that I get is full of weird symbols. I also tried to do:
     `char delim = '0';`
     `ostream_iterator<unsigned short> o_iter(outfile, &delim);`
But I'm also getting weird symbols

Comment: @RoronoaZoro : Is this when compiling the example above or when integrating the above code samples into your own code?  I'm assuming when you aren't using the deliminator argument, that everything works fine?

Comment: @Jason : Yes, that's when using code almost identical to the above. When I don't use the delimiter, I can read the data in a text editor (I see the number), but when using the delimiter I get weird symbols. I'm trying to figure out what that is.

Comment: @RoronoaZoro: What happens if you use `std::cout` for your iterator?  Do you still get "weird symbols"?  For instance, here is a compiled version here: http://ideone.com/tTMWh ... see if when you compile that version, you get the same output on your own machine.

Comment: @Jason: When I compile the code in the link you sent me, I don't see any weird symbols in my command prompt. It seems that when the output is a file (.txt), I'm getting the data in binary format, because when I tried to binary-read the file using Matlab, I was able to read each number individually, so for example I read _48(for 0), 9(for tab), 48(for 0),..._ I can work with that but it's sort of a pain.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* just cast the pointer.

```
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&testDump[0]), testDump.size() * sizeof(unsigned short));
```

Be aware that the resulting file is formatted in a way that's specific to your particular platform/implementation. So you can't necessarily read it back in the obvious way on an incompatible machine.

On Windows, that will give you a 400MB-ish file, with each of the 204800000 pairs of bytes representing a little-endian unsigned short.

This should be reasonably fast. I find it difficult to believe that your task really is to save the data "using the fastest approach". How would anyone know that your code really is optimal, that there doesn't exist other code that would do it one nanosecond faster? And what would be the point of going to any extra effort to shave off a nanosecond? And so on.

Certainly it might be faster to use a quick streaming compression algorithm to reduce the disk space required, since the operation is likely to be bound by disk I/O. But the code would be much more complex, and whether it helps or not depends how compressible the data is.

Comment: I think the OP has only about 400MB of data.

Comment: @Kerrek: you're right, the question has been edited to that effect. I believed the number in the example code, instead of the text.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Your method is super fast (less than one second). However, I'm getting weird symbols when I open the output file. Do you have any advice? I would also like to add separators between data points, is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @Roronoa: open the output file in what? A text editor? Then of course it has weird symbols in, since my code doesn't write the values as text. I think you need to ask another question, specifying what this file is actually *for*, and asking what format you should therefore save it in.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Sorry about the confusion/vagueness. The values that I'm trying to store to my hard disk are pixel values (from 0 to 255). I want to later on convert them to images using Matlab. I saved the file as .txt and tried to open it in a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

A cross platform way of serializing this would be to just fixate on little endian representation for short and dump all the shorts. This would avoid the ASCII data-bloat in Jason's solution and at the same time be cross platform.

So, I would just do

```
ofstream outfile("allMyNumbers.data", ios::out | ios::binary);
for(int k = 0; k < testDump.size(); k++)
{
    unsigned short leData = htole16(testDump[k]);    
    outfile.write(&leData, sizeof(leData));
}
```

The implementation of htole16 (host to little endian for 16 bit integers) is the following:

For x86, x64:

```
unsigned short htole16(unsigned short x)
{
    return x;
}
```

For big endian machines such as Sparc / PowerPC (though none of this would run Windows 7)

```
unsigned short htole16(unsigned short x)
{
    return _byteswap_ushort(x);
}
```

Comment: This is only "cross-platform" because you've pre-defined how the binary data will be formatted ... if the reader has no idea what the agreed-upon formatting of the data is, then it's not "cross-platform".

Comment: The reader (program) would also need to _know_ that the data is in ASCII tab delimited notation before it attempts to read it. Besides, a similar technique using big endian formatting is used in networking protocols to achieve cross platform data representation. The byte order is called "network byte order" and the C functions commonly used are htons() and ntohs(). The above is a variant of this (popular) technique.

Comment: I realize you are using a variation of a networking technique where network-byte-order is standardized on a big-endian representation for multi-byte data blocks.  I'll give you a +1 then since otherwise we'll just be talking in circles for whose standard is more "standardized" than the other's :-)

Comment: @Jason: if you want a "standard" representation, then JSON might not be a bad idea. It's a small tweak to your code to output a JSON array of numbers, and it's only 2 bytes bigger.

Comment: I did some work sometime back where I had to store a large number of doubles and integers in a file and process them numerically in different ways. I saw that keeping them represented in ASCII incurred a huge computational overhead in printf / scanf routines. Later I just "standardized" on a binary format and had tools to print them in human form if I needed that. That made my processing tools much faster because of lack of repeated binary <-> ASCII conversions. The format really depends on usage characteristics IMHO.